# Insert half rows of data in one table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using sql server 2012.

Is there any queries where I can insert half the number of rows from one table into another table. The number of rows does not have to be exactly half.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`TOP xxx PERCENT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx), in your case "half" means "50 percent":

```
insert into another_table(col1, col2, col3)
select top 50 percent col1, col2, col3
from one_table
```